# Text formatting inside Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm struggling to get some finer layout issues working on a WPF button, essentially I'm trying to centre the text inside the button? At the moment I dynamically set several buttons in code with something similar to

```
        button1.Content = (option1 != 0.0)
            ? option1.ToString() + "\n"   +  "Centre"
            : string.Empty;
        button2.Content = (option2 != 0.0)
            ? option2.ToString() + "\n"   + "Quite"
            : string.Empty;
        button3.Content = (option3 != 0.0)
            ? option.ToString() + "\n" + "Not"
            : string.Empty;
```

and in XAML both vertical and horizontal content alignment is centre?

```
<Button Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="254,0,0,0" Name="button1"
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Click="button_Click" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10"
       FontStretch="SemiCondensed"/>
```

but this doesn't give me the layout I desire, (see below)

[image]

1. How do get both the values on top to be centred and the text on the bottom to be centred?
2. If I wanted the bottom text to have font size 10 **bold** and the top to be font size 14 normal - how do I do that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use two Textblocks inside the Button and to setup databindings.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" >
    <Button Height="50" Width="80">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1}" FontSize="14"  />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2}" FontSize="10"  FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
     public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Text1 = "10";
        Text2 = "TEST Test";
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

please also read MVVM / INotifyPropertychanged tutorials if you don't already know this patterns (because my example does not implement this interface, the content of the buttonts will not refresh if you change a TextX property)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Path=Option1, Converter={StaticResource myDoubleToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Option1}"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
```

you now don`t need set text in code. just realize *myDoubleToVisibilityConverter* and *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface

Direct setting of Button`s content, in this case, is some sort of violation on WPF ideology.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code (\r\n)

```
 button1.Content = (option1 != 0.0)
            ? option1.ToString() + "\r\n"   +  "Centre"
            : string.Empty;
```

You can also use `Environment.NewLine`